# Regex for number range not working in jquery validation

Tags: jquery, regex, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate

In an asp.net mvc3 view, I have a form with an input. The input has regex for a number range. The regex is correct, but the validation *always* comes back as invalid. I am not sure what I am missing here. This is the rendered element. It is appended to the DOM after the page loads at runtime.

```
<input 
 id="ReserveQuantity" 
 class="text-box single-line" 
 type="text" 
 name="ReserveQuantity" 
 data-val="true" 
 data-val-required="required." 
 data-val-number="numeric" 
 data-val-regex-pattern="/^(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|10[0-4])$/" 
 data-val-regex="The field must be in range 0 to 104."
>
```

What am I missing to make this properly validate? Did I miss a call to the jquery validator when rendering this dynamically or is the problem elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No clue why the regex doesn't validate properly **and am still open to explanations!** The regex is formed right, and I even tried a couple different scenarios all which did not properly validate. I *was* at a loss until I discovered a masterfully written blog post: http://xhalent.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/arbitrary-client-side-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3/

As a result, I made the following changes:

```
data-val-regex-pattern="/^(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|10[0-4])$/" 
data-val-regex="The field must be in range 0 to 104."
```

Became

```
data-val-range="The field must be in range 0 to 104." 
data-val-range-min="0" 
data-val-range-max="104"
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: I know this is a bit old, but I noticed that writing the pattern starting and finishing with a '/', causes some unexpected behaviors. Have you tried without the slashes?

Comment: @Dorival - I am not sure if I tried without the slashes, but I assume so? It was a while ago. I was never able to make the regex properly work in all of my testing scenarios. I moved to the data value ranges and custom validation for more complex situations. If you are able to get the regex to work feel free to please post an answer with your findings and I will review if it is more relevant than this workaround.